# How to Parse Microdata in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing, schema, microdata

What is the best way to Parse the Microdata from HTML using PHP in WordPress? Here is the complete scenario.

1. I am using a curl request to get the 3rd party data.
2. I can successfully parse the data from `<script type="application/ld+json">` tag using regex.
3. When URL does not have the '' and the schema was set with `itemprop` OR with Microdata way that time I am facing an issue.

Can you please help me out with the best approach in WordPress OR PHP way?

Let me know if more input is required.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sanket  - how did you come along - do you have solved the issues. Look forward to hear from you

Comment: You can make it work with the help of xpath.
```$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML( $response['body'] );
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query('//*[@itemprop]');```

Comment: hello dear Sanket - many thanks for your answer and  for sharing your insights. Great to see that you have been able to come along with a solution - this looks impressive and convincing. BTW: At the moment i am also workin on a solution in a parserer that fetches Wordpress-plugin-Metadata using simple_html_dom 
- would be glad if you have a little reviewing look on the soutions - see my last question - in my profile. Thanks alot for your help. Have a great day.